# Reduce button text size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` with `setBackgroundImage:` and used `setTitle:` for text. But the text size is too big. How to reduce the text size.

```
 prevBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [prevBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"previous_iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [prevBtn addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(goPrev:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 [prevBtn setTitle:@"Previous" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 prevBtn.frame = CGRectMake(2, 5, 85, 30);
```

Comment: Set font like, `[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the font of the button, like this:

```
float size = 14.0; //assign size any value you wish for the font size.
prevBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:size];
```

Comment: What advantage does doing `int size = 14` over `prevBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];`? Why add the redundant extra line in?

Comment: Also why the `int` `systemFontOFSize:` takes a `float` not an `int`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this. It will automatically reduce the text size when it does not fit with minimum font size 10:

```
 prevBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [prevBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"previous_iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [prevBtn addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(goPrev:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 [prevBtn setTitle:@"Previous" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 prevBtn.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
 prevBtn.titleLabel.minimumFontSize = 10;
 prevBtn.frame = CGRectMake(2, 5, 85, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[prevButton.titleLabel setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 13.0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[prevBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
```